# Access dataBase using Apache-Spark-SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi i'm a new learner for apache spark using java
**This is a correct way or not?
This code is working,but performance wise very slow i don't know which one is best approach to access data for every loop.**

```
Dataset<Row> javaRDD = sparkSession.read().jdbc(dataBase_url, "sample", properties);

javaRDD.toDF().registerTempTable("sample"); 

Dataset<Row> Users = sparkSession.sql("SELECT DISTINCT FROM_USER FROM sample ");

List<Row> members = Users.collectAsList();

for (Row row : members) {

 Dataset<Row> userConversation = sparkSession.sql("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM sample WHERE FROM_USER ='"+ row.getDecimal(0) +"'");
 userConversation.show();

}
```

Comment: You're executing a query for every iteration of a loop. That's always going to be slow.

Comment: thnx,any other approach to access it using spark code?

Comment: Of course. It wouldn't be very useful if the only way to do things were the slow and bad way.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a set with all Users and then execute a query like

```
sparkSession.sql("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM sample WHERE FROM_USER IN usersSet);
```

This way you execute only one query so you pay the overhead needed to DB connection only once.

Another approach if you run Spark over HDFS and this is a one time query is to use a tool like [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/) to load the SQL table in Hadoop and use the data natively in Spark.